# Is There a Groovier Way To Add Dashes to a String?

Tags: string, groovy

I have the following code, which works, but I'm wondering if there is a "groovier" way of doing this:

```
/**
   * 10 digit - #-######-##-#
   * 13 digit - ###-#-######-##-#
   * */
private formatISBN(String isbn) {
  if (isbn?.length() == 10) {
    def part1 = isbn.substring(0, 1)
    def part2 = isbn.substring(1, 7)
    def part3 = isbn.substring(7, 9)
    def part4 = isbn.substring(9, 10)
    return "${part1}-${part2}-${part3}-${part4}"
  } else if (isbn?.length() == 13) {
    def part1 = isbn.substring(0, 3)
    def part2 = isbn.substring(3, 4)
    def part3 = isbn.substring(4, 10)
    def part4 = isbn.substring(10, 12)
    def part5 = isbn.substring(12, 13)
    return "${part1}-${part2}-${part3}-${part4}-${part5}"
  } else {
    return isbn
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dunno if I like this any better. I'd make the position map a static final, too.

```
private isbnify(String isbn) {
  def dashesAt = [ 10: [[0,1], [1,7], [7,9],  [9,10]],
                   13: [[0,3], [3,4], [4,10], [10,12], [12,13]]]
  def dashes = dashesAt[isbn?.length()]
  (dashes == null) ? isbn 
                   : dashes.collect { isbn.substring(*it) }.join('-')
}
```

Ranges make for a bit less clutter, IMO:

```
private isbnify3(String isbn) {
  def dashesAt = [ 10: [0, 1..6, 7..8, 9],
                   13: [0..2, 3, 4..9, 10..11, 12]]
  def dashes = dashesAt[isbn?.length()]
  dashes == null ? isbn : dashes.collect { isbn[it] }.join("-")
}
```

With an inject-with-two-accumulators it should be easy to do a list-of-dash-positions version, too.

Comment: Can you explain the *it part?  What does the * do in that case?

Comment: @Gregg It de-structures the array so it looks like the two individual substring parameters. It should work without it, though, I think. I couldn't tell you why it would, though, which is why I was chicken and left it in.

Answer (score 12):

You could first use the `[]` string operator to get the substrings instead of `substring` and drop the intermediate variables. For example in the case for `length == 10`:

```
"${isbn[0]}-${isbn[1..6]}-${isbn[7..8]}-${isbn[9]}"
```

Now, there is a bit of repetition there. You can get instead first get all the `isbn` segments and then `.join` them with `'-'`:

```
[isbn[0], isbn[1..6], isbn[7..8], isbn[9]].join('-')
```

And, even further, instead of referencing `isbn` every time, you can make a list of the ranges you want to get and then get them all the same time using `collect`:

```
[0, 1..6, 7..8, 9].collect { isbn[it] }.join('-')
```

If you're going for code golfing, you can also do:

```
('-'+isbn)[1, 0, 2..7, 0, 8..9, 0, 10]
```

I'll leave it to you to figure out how that works, but i guess it's probably not a good idea to leave that on production code, unless you want to surprise future maintainers hehe.

---

Also, notice that the format when `length == 13` is the same as for `length == 10` but with a different prefix, you can then reuse the same function in that case. The whole function (with a couple of tests) would be:

```
/**
 * 10 digit - #-######-##-#
 * 13 digit - ###-#-######-##-#
 **/
def formatIsbn(isbn) {
    switch (isbn?.length()) {
        case 10: return [0, 1..6, 7..8, 9].collect { isbn[it] }.join('-')
        case 13: return isbn.take(3) + '-' + formatIsbn(isbn.drop(3))
        default: return isbn
    }
}

assert formatIsbn('abcdefghij') == 'a-bcdefg-hi-j'
assert formatIsbn('abcdefghijklm') == 'abc-d-efghij-kl-m'
```

---

Now, i think there are some bad smells in that code. Can `isbn` be `null`? At least to me, this doesn't look like a function that needs to bother about the nullity of its argument, or at least that's not clear by reading its name (it should be called something like `formatIsbnOrNull` instead if both ISBN strings and null values are accepted). If null values are not valid, then let it blow up with a `NullPointerException` when accessing `isbn.length()` so the caller know they have passed a wrong argument, instead of silently returning the same null.

The same goes for the `return ISBN` at the end. Is it expected for that function to receive a string that's neither 10 nor 13 characters long? If not, better `throw new IllegalArgumentException()` and let the caller know they have called it wrongly.

---

Finally, i'm not sure if this is the most "readable" solution. Another possible solution is having a string for the format, like `'###-#-######-##-#'` and then replace the `#`s by the `isbn` characters. I think it might be more self-documenting:

```
def formatIsbn(isbn) {
    def format = [
        10: '#-######-##-#',
        13: '###-#-######-##-#'
    ][isbn.length()]
    def n = 0
    format.replaceAll(/#/) { isbn[n++] }
}
```

Comment: This is all great.  Thanks for the detailed answer.  I'm not sure which to go with yet.  If I end up using yours, I'll change my accepted answer.

Comment: I think the last one is the best, if a bit opaque--but IMO it's unlikely a maintainer would care about anything except the patterns, if even that. The ranges solution is the same; I can't decide which I like better between pattern/ranges.

Comment: @Gregg Another possibility that i didn't mention here is making a generic function `partition(str, sizes)` that takes a string and returns a list of sub-strings of given sizes (e.g. `partition('hello', [4, 1]) == ['hell', 'o']`) so then getting the ISBN can be expressed as "partition the original string taking 1, 6, 2 and 1 characters and join them with dashes": `partition(isbn, [1, 6, 2, 1]).join('-')`. It takes a bit more coding that generic function, but the implementation of `formatIsbn` gets very clan :)

Comment: ^ Forget about that, a regex is much simpler and just as readable in this case. I think [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11355116/581845) is the best solution :)

Answer (score 4):

Consider adding the method to the String class, as shown here. Note that this answer is a spin on a clever suggestion in epidemian's answer (re: collect).

Note:

This code augments String with `asIsbn`().

The range [0..2] does not need the call to `asIsbn`(), but the symmetry of using `collect` twice is irresistable.

Groovy returns the last expression in `if/else`, so 'return' is not necessary

```
/**
 * 10 digit - #-######-##-#
 * 13 digit - ###-#-######-##-#
 **/
String.metaClass.asIsbn = { ->
    if (delegate.length() == 10) {
        [0, 1..6, 7..8, 9].collect { delegate[it] }.join('-')
    } else if (delegate.length() == 13) {
        [0..2, 3..12].collect { delegate[it].asIsbn() }.join('-')
    } else {
        delegate
    }
}

assert "abcdefghij".asIsbn() == 'a-bcdefg-hi-j'
assert "abcdefghijklm".asIsbn() == 'abc-d-efghij-kl-m'
assert "def".asIsbn() == "def"
String s = null 
assert s?.asIsbn() == null
```

Comment: +1 for the _sexiness_ of `[0..2, 3..12].collect { delegate[it].asIsbn() }` =D

Answer (score 3):

I would try using `Regex`... I think it's pretty much readable if you know how to use regex, and it's javascript inspired syntax in groovy is pretty cool also.

One more thing: it's pretty clear, looking at the capture groups, what your string looks like for the desired formatting.

```
private formatISBN(String isbn) {
    if (isbn?.length() == 10) {
        m = isbn =~ /(\d{1})(\d{6})(\d{2})(\d{1})/
        return "${m[0][1]}-${m[0][2]}-${m[0][3]}-${m[0][4]}"
    } else if (isbn?.length() == 13) {
        m = isbn =~ /(\d{3})(\d{1})(\d{6})(\d{2})(\d{1})/
        return "${m[0][1]}-${m[0][2]}-${m[0][3]}-${m[0][4]}-${m[0][5]}"        
    } else {
        return isbn
    }
}
```

Btw, @epidemian suggestion using backreferences is great! I think the code would look like:

```
private formatISBN(String isbn) {
    if (isbn?.length() == 10) {
        return isbn.replaceAll(/(\d{1})(\d{6})(\d{2})(\d{1})/, '$1-$2-$3-$4')
    } else if (isbn?.length() == 13) {
        return isbn.replaceAll(/(\d{3})(\d{1})(\d{6})(\d{2})(\d{1})/, '$1-$2-$3-$4-$5')
    } else {
        return isbn
    }
}
```

Comment: I really like the regex in this case; it very readable! But i think the replacement part is too repetitive. Maybe you could use something like `(isbn =~ /(\d{1})(\d{6})(\d{2})(\d{1})/)[0].tail().join('-')`, or `isbn.replaceAll(/(\d{1})(\d{6})(\d{2})(\d{1})/, '$1-$2-$3-$4')`? =D

Comment: Whoa, `isbn.replaceAll(/(\d{1})(\d{6})(\d{2})(\d{1})/, '$1-$2-$3-$4')` is very very clever :D

Comment: Without back-references I really don't like the regex solution, to be honest--even with, I find the code difficult to look at from an aesthetic standpoint.

Comment: One thing I would like to add is that the same regex could be used to validate your input, which is something we haven't discussed about.

Answer (score 0):

This should be a comment to @everton, but I don't have the 50 reputation needed to do that yet. So this answer is really just a suggested variation on @everton's answer.

One less regex by making the first 3 digits optional. The downside is having to remove a leading '-' if the ISBN is 10 characters. (I also prefer `\d` over `\d{1}`.)

```
private formatISBN(String isbn) {
  String result = isbn.replaceAll(/^(\d{3})?(\d)(\d{6})(\d{2})(\d)$/,
                                  '$1-$2-$3-$4-$5')
  if (result) {
    return result.startsWith('-') ? result[1..-1] : result
  } else {
    return isbn // return value unchanged, pattern didn't match
  }
}

println formatISBN('1234567890')
println formatISBN('9991234567890')
println formatISBN('123456789') // test an ISBN that's too short
println formatISBN('12345678901234') // test an ISBN that's too long
```